# Running Out of Time

Tags: chess

You are playing with the black pieces and you know you have about a second before you run out of time and lose the game.

There is no time added to the clock and white has plenty of time left. What move do you play?

[image]

Comment: Is there a limit to the speed at which you can move pieces?

Comment: I think in other words he is looking for the least number of moves to check the white king, because for now I don't see any fast checkmates

Comment: Is lateral thinking allowed?

Comment: @WilliamPennanti assume you can make just a few moves before you run out of time.

Comment: @Smartest1here it is a tricky question; based on a tricky rule:) I wouldn't say it is lateral though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would play

> **1...Rg8xg6+** (or **1...Rg1xg6+** would work as well)

and then

> after White plays the forced **2.Nf4xg6+**, I play **2...Rg1xg6+**. Now White must capture the rook with **3.Kh6xg6+**. Now just capture the White's rook with the queen **3... Qb5xh5+** (actually, Black *has to* do it as an only way to get rid out of check), and White has again nothing except capturing the queen (with any of his remaining pieces, the king or the knight). All White's and Black's (except the first of course) moves are forced and lead to KN vs K, which is immediately declared draw by insufficient material.

Thanks go to @LeppyR64.

Comment: Nxg6 by black delivers check and must be dealt with first.  I like your answer a lot though!

Comment: That's right, but the reason why Rg8xg6+ works is that even if you run out of time immediately, the draw is guaranteed. Indeed, if the opponent does not have a path to win, the game is automatically a draw. If you add this info to the answer, I will accept it:)